# How to make if operator work without reloading page? JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was learning jQuery, trying to make slider and I almost did it, but I faced with the problem, after 2 time slider goes through the images the first image dose not appear. I was using margin-left to make images move.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.slides').css('margin-left') === '-3600px') {
      $('.slides').animate({
        'margin-left': -0.05
      });
    } else {
      $('.slides').animate({
        'margin-left': '-=720'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Aslan and welcome to Stack Overflow. As I don't have a visual demo of the problem, I assume that your image widths of all images is 720 Pixels and you want to show 5 pictures next to one another.

On your **first** iteration you have a `margin-left` of 0.

- Button clicked 1 -> `margin-left: 720px;`
- Button clicked 2 -> `margin-left: 1440px;`
- Button clicked 3 -> `margin-left: 2160px;`
- Button clicked 4 -> `margin-left: 2880px;`
- Button clicked 5 -> `margin-left: 3600px;`

Now you click the button again and move the scrollbar back to its position which is now not at `margin: 0`, but `margin: -0.05`. We start **iteration 2**:

- Button clicked 1 -> `margin-left: 719.95px;`
- Button clicked 2 -> `margin-left: 1439.95px;`
- Button clicked 3 -> `margin-left: 2159.95px;`
- Button clicked 4 -> `margin-left: 2879.95px;`
- Button clicked 5 -> `margin-left: 3599.95px;`

But you **check for an exact margin-left of 3600** and not 3599.95.

You either need to set `margin-left: 0` when scrolling back or query for a left margin of 3599 or greater:

```
if ($('.slides').css('margin-left') >= '3599px') {
  $('.slides').animate({
        'margin-left': -0.05
      });
}
```